# Opendistro Kibana: get user information (like roles) in a plugin

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro, kibana-plugin

I am developing a Kibana plugin displaying a list of items. Some of these items needs to be highlighted if created by a certain team.

The idea is to attribute a specific role to the members of the team to distinguish them from other users, so I need to be able to check the roles of the active users when a new item is created.

Is there a way to retrieve this kind of information from the server-side or the client-side?

I tried server-side but adding `opendistro_security` to the dependencies of my plugin prevents it to start.

We are using the version 1.8.0 of the OpenDistro plugins and the plugin I am working on uses the new plugin platform.

Thank you!